# What is the difference between "professional" and "vocational"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "professional" and "vocational"? For example,

> After high school graduation, she sought some "professional"/"vocational" training in a community college in order to work as a office clerk in the future.

Which word is more appropriate here?

Comment: *Vocations* almost always carry the connotation of some kind of manual labor (plumber, carpenter, electrician, mechanic, etc). By contrast, "profession" implies some kind of white collar job (historically the contrast was much stronger, but today any kind of "knowledge worker", including being a clerk, is considered a "professional").

Comment: [seek, sought, sought]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I copied from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-a-vocation-profession-and-occupation?share=1):

> A **vocation** is generally a job that requires a particular set of
>   skills acquired through experience or through training but not
>   necessarily dependent on a college degree. These would include
>   plumbing, electrician, mechanic, etc.
>
> A **profession** could be one of the above but generally references a
>   doctor, lawyer, nurse or other skilled worker who was required to
>   obtain college/university training.

Here are some points from the "[Difference Between](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-vocation-and-vs-profession/)" site:

> - Though both vocation, as well as profession, indicates the career or the occupation through which an individual makes a livelihood,
>     vocation is a broader term than profession.
> - Profession refers to the career that one opts for, getting extensive training and acquiring special skills to become eligible for a job in
>     it.
> - Profession requires training and qualification whereas vocation is the innate ability in an individual towards a particular occupation.